# WPF The name '' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having an issue that I cannot figure out.  Trying to call a function from a class in the same name space.  Here is my class;

```
namespace MYNAMESPACE{
class myClass
{
    public static string myFunction(string s)
    {
        //Function Logic
    }
}}
```

Then in my windows;

```
namespace MYNAMESPACE{
public partial class myWindow : Window
{
    public myWindow()
    {
        string s1; 
        s1 = myFunction("My string");

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}}
```

The problem is calling the function gives "The name '' does not exist in the current context".  Yet if I change the it to this it works;

```
s1 = MYNAMESPACE.myClass.myFunction("My string");
```

Why is it not in context?

Comment: Why do you think it would exist there? It's in a different class, after all...

Comment: You need to instantiate an instance of myClass in MyWindow.

Comment: @Chris no, he doesn't. The method is `static`.

Comment: @Jesse C Slicer, correct, I didn't notice it was static :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because myClass and myWindow are not the same context. The current context of your line in question is MYNAMESPACE.myWindow and there is no function called myFunction in this context. So you need to spell out the whole context as you did.

Answer (score 3):

This error can appear for several different reasons. It happened to me when I attempted to use a view inside a DataTemplate. For example:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <views:MyView x:Name="MyViewControl"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
<Grid>
```

WPF Rookie mistake; the code-behind will not recognize *MyViewControl* if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Check the .NET framework both the reference and the project is built on. Change it to latest .NET framework in the project properties, clean the solution and rebuild it.